# convert a generic date into datetime in python (pandas)

Tags: python, datetime, type-conversion

Good Afternoon,

I have a huge dataset where time informations are stored as a float64 (or integer) in one column of the dataframe in format 'ddmmyyyy' (ex. 20 January 2020 would be the float 20012020.0). I need to convert it into a datetime like 'dd-mm-yyyy'. I saw the function to_datetime, but i can't really manage to obtain what i want. Does someone know how to do it?

Massimo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try converting to string and after that, to date format, you want like this:

```py
# The first step is to change the type of the column, 
# in order to get rid of the .0 we will change first to int and then to
# string

df["date"] = df["date"].astype(int)
df["date"] = df["date"].astype(str)

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    # In case that the date format is similar to 20012020
    x = str(df["date"].iloc[i])
    if len(x) == 8:
        df.at[i,'date'] = "{}-{}-{}".format(x[:2], x[2:4], x[4:])
    # In case that the format is similar to 1012020
    else:
        df.at[i,'date'] = "0{}-{}-{}".format(x[0], x[1:3], x[3:])
```

**Edit:**

- As you said this solution only works if the month always comes in 2
  digits.
- Added missing variable in the loop
- Added change column types before entering the loop.

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: EnriqueBet, unfortunately i got error "'int' object is not subscriptable".

Comment: Sorry about that, my parentheses were bad places, I just edited the code, could you try again please?

Comment: EnriqueBet, thanks! this works for every date that is a integer like 20122020, but for dates like 9012020 (9 jan 2020), the code doesn't work. The year and the month are always stored with two digits, but the day is sometimes 1 digit (1 to 9) and sometimes 2 digits (10 to end of the month).

Comment: should i add for x in df['date'] after format? because in this case x is undefined

Comment: Just edited again the post. I forgot to add something in the code. Could you please check again?

Comment: It shows the error: "invalid literal for int() with base 10: '14-09-2012'"

Comment: In that case, we will need to add them to another column, let me edit once again. This error is shown because the column where we are trying to write is of type float.

Comment: Now it displays: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds at this line  x = str(df["date"].iloc[i])

Comment: Can you send an example of your data frame? I tried with one that I made randomly and worked fine.

Comment: ok i have some inconsistencies in the dataframe size, i didn't notice it before.. let me check and correct and then i will let you know if everything is working fine.

Comment: Thanks so much, now that i corrected the dataframe it works smoothly! ;)

Comment: You are very welcome! I am glad that the solution worked for you. Good luck with your project! :D